# talkback calls my content description twice

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback, android-a11y

I have an item that steals the focus when its hosting activity is opened.

But then in talkback mode it's read twice.

1) how can i define an item to be read as soon as the activity it opned?

2) what can cause its content description to be read twice?

3) Is there a way to define content description to be read after click?

I saw this [doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility), but didn't find out answers.

Answer (score 1):

The question lacks some specifics, but here are some answers.

1 - The screen reader will automatically focus and read the first view on the screen (from right to left, top to bottom). This is the default behavior and should not be changed.

2 - In some cases, the screen reader may perform a different action when your content is shown. For example, when a `Dialog` is shown, the default behavior for `TalkBack` is to announce the title and focus on the second view. If you are manually requesting the reader to focus on the title, it may be read twice.

3 - You can define the text to be read in your XML with [android:contentDescription](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:contentDescription), or in your code with `view.setContentDescription(textToRead)`

Answer (score 0):

It seems if the outer container is 'focusable' then it might announce the content twice.
For example:

```
<FrameLayout focusable='true'>
    <TextView/>
</FrameLayout>
```

So, for me the fix was to make the outer container 'not focusable'